# Table row drag using react-sortable-hoc removes already applied css on table row

Tags: reactjs, react-sortable-hoc

I am using react-sortable-hoc for drag and drop. But as soon as i drag a table row, all the styling of table row goes away and it looks bad until I drop the row

Comment: You need to pass the style attribute down to the div itself.

Comment: @Amir-Mousavi It is inside table>tr>td

Comment: If you can make a sample sandbox out of your code (or if the original project is yet small paste all of it). then it would be easier to help you.

Comment: Also, this [issue on GitHub](https://github.com/clauderic/react-sortable-hoc/issues/259) might be helpful

Comment: Here is the full working example            https://codesandbox.io/s/react-sortable-hoc-antd-table-column-width-bug-fix-forked-ddtt7g?file=/demo.js:3427-3457